# Construct a matrix in openCV based on a given matrix

Tags: c++, python, opencv, computer-vision

I am writing some code using the OpenCV library in Python. In the process, I need to construct a matrix based on another matrix given. Now my code looks like the following:

```
for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, height):
        if I_mat[x][y]>=0 and I_mat[x][y]<=c_low:
            w_mat[x][y] = float(I_mat[x][y])/c_low
        elif I_mat[x][y]>c_low and I_mat[x][y]<c_high:
            w_mat[x][y] = 1
        else:
            w_mat[x][y] = float((255-I_mat[x][y]))/float((255-c_high))
```

where, **I_mat** is the input matrix and **w_mat** is the matrix I am going to construct. Since the input matrix is quite large, this algorithm is quite slow. I wonder if there are any other methods to construct **w_mat** more efficiently. Thank a lot!

(It is not necessary to show the solution in Python.)

Answer (score 0):

edit:you might want to use numba

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
from numba import void,jit

c_low = .3
c_high = .6
def func(val):
    if val>=0 and val<=c_low:
        return float(val)/c_low
    elif val>c_low and val<c_high:
        return 1.
    else:
        return (255.-val)/(255.-c_high)

def npvectorize(): 
    global w_mat
    vfunc = np.vectorize(func)
    w_mat = vfunc(I_mat)

def orig():
    for x in range(I_mat.shape[0]):
        for y in range(I_mat.shape[1]):
            if I_mat[x][y]>=0 and I_mat[x][y]<=c_low:
                w_mat[x][y] = float(I_mat[x][y])/c_low
            elif I_mat[x][y]>c_low and I_mat[x][y]<c_high:
                w_mat[x][y] = 1
            else:
                w_mat[x][y] = float((255-I_mat[x][y]))/float((255-c_high))

I_mat = np.array(np.random.random((1000,1000)), dtype = np.float)
w_mat = np.empty_like(I_mat)

fast = jit(void(),nopython=True)(orig)

print timeit.Timer(fast).timeit(1)
print timeit.Timer(npvectorize).timeit(1)
print timeit.Timer(orig).timeit(1)
```

output:

```
0.0352660446331
0.472590475098
4.78634474265
```